# How to create summary/notes without using the Route attribute

Tags: servicestack, swagger, servicestack-bsd

I wanted to create the summaries in code behind because all of my routes are currently configured in the AppConfig class, but as far as I can tell, summaries can only be included using the Route attribute.

EX:

```cs
[Route("/myrequest/{Id}, "GET", Summary="My Summary", Notes="My Notes")]
public class MyRequest : IReturn<MyResponse>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

yet my routes are configured like:

```cs
base.Routes
    .Add<MyRequest>("/myrequest", "GET");
```

Essentially I'd like to do something like:

```cs
base.Routes
    .Add<MyRequest>("/myrequest", "GET", "My Summary", "My Notes");
```

Is there currently a way to do this?

**EDIT:**

I'm using ServiceStack version 3.9.71

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I took another look at adding routes and found there actually is an overload that allows you to specify the summary and notes.

Here's how to do it:

```cs
base.Routes
    .Add(typeof(MyRequest), "/myrequest", "GET", "My Summary", "My Notes");
```

I really wish ServiceStack would add an overload to the Generic Add method so I wouldn't have to specify the type in this way.

**EDIT:**

I decided to write an extension method to get the method I was initially looking for.

```cs
public static class RouteExtensions
{
    public static ServiceStack.ServiceHost.IServiceRoutes Add<T>(
        this ServiceStack.ServiceHost.IServiceRoutes route, 
        string restPath,
        string verbs,
        string summary,
        string notes)
    {
        route.Add(typeof(T), restPath, verbs, summary, notes);

        return route;
    }
}
```

Now I can do this:

```cs
base.Routes
    .Add<MyRequest>("/myrequest", "GET", "My Summary", "My Notes");
```